# Assembly language guessing game. My code kept looping even though the guess should be correct?

Tags: assembly, mips

im really new in this so not even sure I even code this correctly. My first time in fact.
So, I think i did every correct? Im not sure why it wont exit the loop since
`beq $t1, $t0, winExit` should make it quit my loop. The same problem is with loseExit also. Maybe this is all wrong... if it is my bad >.>

```
# The program will ask the player to try to guess the secret number 
# and receive a numerical input from the players.

    .data

# constant strings

prompt1:    .asciiz "Please guess the secret number (up to 10 tries): "
tooHigh:    .asciiz "Incorrect: Number is too high\n"
tooLow:     .asciiz "Incorrect: Number is too low\n"
userWin:    .asciiz "Congratulation! You guessed the secret number! :D"
userLose:   .asciiz "Sorry, You lose :/"

    .text

main:
#start of the loop
loop:
#Set secret number
    li $t0,4            #$t0 hold the secret number: 4
    li $t1,9            #$t1 hold the maximum number of tries: 10
    li $t2,0            #$t2 hold the number of tries. (counter)

#Prompt user for a number
    li $v0,4            #code for print_string
    la $a0,prompt1      #point to $a0 to prompt strings
    syscall             #print prompt

#Get integer from user
    li $v0,5            #code for read_int
    syscall             #get integer from user --> returned in $v0
    move    $s0,$v0     #move the resulting int to $s0

#$s0 hold the guess number

#check if it is equal, if it is then exit loop
    beq $t1, $t0, winExit       #Brand if Equal. User guess the correct number.

    addi $t2,$t2,1              # +1 to counter
    beq  $t2,$t1, loseExit      #check if counter reach the maximum number

    blt $s0,$t0, lessThan       #Branch on Lower Than. check if guess number is less than secret number
    bgt $s0,$t0, greaterThan    #Branch on Greater Than. check if guess number is higher than secret number
    j loop                      #goes back to loop

#prompt guess number is too high then loop
greaterThan:    
    li  $v0,4           #code for print_string
    la  $a0, tooHigh    #point $a0 to tooLow string
    syscall             #print prompt
    j loop      
    #go back to loop

#prompt guess number is too low then loop
lessThan:               
    li  $v0,4           #code for print_string
    la  $a0, tooLow     #point $a0 to tooLow string
    syscall             #print prompt
    j loop      #go back to loop

#print userWin to congratulate user
winExit:
    li  $v0,4           #code for print_string
    la  $a0, userWin    #point $a0 to userWin string
    syscall             #print prompt
    j exitProgram

#print userLose to user
loseExit:

    li  $v0,4           #code for print_string
    la  $a0, userLose   #point $a0 to userLose string
    syscall             #print prompt
    j exitProgram

#Exit program
exitProgram:
    li $v0,10           #code for exit
    syscall             #exit program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#$s0 hold the guess number

#check if it is equal, if it is then exit loop
    beq $t1, $t0, winExit       #Brand if Equal. User guess the correct number.
```

Check if what is equal? Not `$s0` so not the guessed number, maybe the number of tries is equal to the secret number? Except these variables are in `t` (temporary) registers, so the syscall may not have preseved them, or it might have, it depends, but just follow the calling convention.

```
loop:
#Set secret number
    li $t0,4            #$t0 hold the secret number: 4
    li $t1,9            #$t1 hold the maximum number of tries: 10
    li $t2,0            #$t2 hold the number of tries. (counter)
```

If the other problem is fixed, this will still give the player infinite retries, because the number of tries keeps being reset to zero on every iteration.

Comment: oh wow im dumb. ty no idea why i was checking that instead of $s0 lol >.>
How do I make it so that it remembers the counter? move it to a register?

Comment: @Qezzz: MARS syscalls don't clobber any registers (other than the return value).  You can assume that everything else survives a syscall itself.  (Some syscalls return in `$v0` or `$a0`, and usually you have to put args in some registers which means your own code has to use them.)